# Tell me how many there are, in Polish

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

Today, you're going to be writing Polish. No, not Polish notation—*Polish*, the actual language spoken in Poland.

Given a number and a noun, output a Polish sentence telling me that there are that many of that thing, using the appropriate template below.

The input consists of an integer in the range from 0 to 200, and a string of 1 to 10 lowercase ASCII letters (the "input noun"). You may accept these inputs in any reasonable format.

The output must consist of one of the below output templates, where the number in the template (if any) has been replaced with the input integer, and the word `kot` in the template has been replaced with the input noun.

### Output templates

If the input number is 0, then use the output template

```
Nie ma żadnych kotów.
```

If the input number is 1, then use the output template

```
Jest 1 kot.
```

If the input number ends with 2, 3, or 4, but does **not** end with 12, 13, or 14, then use the output template

```
Są 4 koty.
```

In any other case, use the output template

```
Jest 8 kotów.
```

Note that the special characters used in these templates are:

- ż (in "żadnych") – U+017C Latin small letter Z with dot above (&zdot;)
- ó (in the suffix "-ów") – U+00F3 Latin small letter O with acute (&oacute;)
- ą (in "Są") – U+0105 Latin small letter A with ogonek (&aogon;)

You may output these characters in any reasonably common character encoding (including HTML entities), and you may use combining characters instead of precomposed characters (or even a mixture of the two).

Note that in [ISO-8859-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2), all ASCII characters as well as the three special characters above are represented with one byte. Therefore, if your program uses no non-ASCII characters besides these three, then you can count each of these three characters as one byte.

### Test cases

```
0 pomidor -> Nie ma żadnych pomidorów.
1 kwiat -> Jest 1 kwiat.
2 dom -> Są 2 domy.
5 wilk -> Jest 5 wilków.
13 komputer -> Jest 13 komputerów.
24 but -> Są 24 buty.
101 kurczak -> Jest 101 kurczaków.
104 wieloryb -> Są 104 wieloryby.
112 post -> Jest 112 postów.
122 balon -> Są 122 balony.
```

### Do plurals in Polish really work that way?

No, plurals in Polish are actually a lot more complicated than this.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in each language wins.

Comment: how much more complicated is real Polish?https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Polish/Nouns_-_Number

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay That page only describes how to form the nominative plural form of a word. Polish has 6 other cases that all have different ways of forming plurals. There's also the question of when the nominative plural is needed and when the genitive plural is needed, and whether the resulting phrase is treated as singular or plural. This challenge touches on all of that, but only for masculine nouns that form the nominative plural with -y and the genitive plural with -ów.

Comment: Specifically, the requirement is only for processing masculine inanimate ("non-virile") nouns.  Imagine the complexity otherwise!

Answer (score 10):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 88 bytes

```
.+
Jest $&ów.
Jest 0
Nie ma żadnych
( 1 .+)...
$1.
Jest (.*(?<!1)[2-4] .+)...
Są $1y.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcyxCsIwFIXh/T7FFYpUiyE31k1wd3BxFIe0DRjaNCVNKXX3iVzd1OeKAXU78H8cp7xuZQgsg73qPSbz531k383hoBUaie@HrNqpvECKhCxbMMYgoZ9K2TLdbWe0OIlVfv7n4@uGCU0sBI6dNbqyDgjrUUsPAitrYIOjbmqgNdbWdINXDkSOxeCBeJSDK68yZp5HpxrrpgKIRDzroxACC9nY9gM) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
Jest $&ów.
```

Assume none of the special cases apply.

```
Jest 0
Nie ma żadnych
```

Fix up if the input was `0`.

```
( 1 .+)...
$1.
```

Fix up if the input was `1`.

```
Jest (.*(?<!1)[2-4] .+)...
Są $1y.
```

Fix up for the `2-4` but not `12-14` endings.

Comment: Impressive! Looks like you're counting ó, ż, and ą as two bytes each, right? Since those are all one byte in ISO-8859-2, I don't see any problem with saying that your program is written in ISO-8859-2 and then counting those as one byte each. See the note about ISO-8859-2 that I just added.

Comment: @TannerSwett Thanks for letting me know, although I won't bother updating my answer just for that change.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>105</s> <s>92</s> 89 bytes

*-16 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).*

```
„ówU’Jî• ’V>iXIŽ1}ç’NíÓ íà ÿ‹¤½Áh ’rJë¹iY…ÿ1 ìë¹Ƶ…S©Å¿O¹®T+Å¿O_*i¹Ƶ¡ç"Sÿ ÿ ÿy"ëY¹ðIXJ]'.J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8w5vLQx81zPQ6vO5RwyIFICvMLjPC8@hew9rDy4E8v8NrD09WABILFA7vf9Sw89CSQ3sPN2aAFBZ5HV59aGdm5KOGZYf3GyocXgPiHtsK5AYfWnm49dB@/0M7D60L0QYz47UyQZKHFh5erhR8eL8CGFUqHV4deWjn4Q2eEV6x6npe//8bGphwlWem5uQXVSYBAA) Takes input separated by a newline.

Comment: `"ÿ1 ÿ"` can be `…ÿ1 ì` for -1; `Ƶ…ε¹sÅ¿}O12 14Ÿε¹sÅ¿}` can be `¹Ƶ…S©Å¿O¹®T+Å¿` for -7; and `Xs¹Y"ÿÿ ÿÿ"` can be `Y¹ðIXJ` for -5: [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//2Najew8vf9Qw7/D@8tBHDTO9Dq971LBIAcgKs8uM8Dy617AWJD3T7/Daw5MVgMQChcP7HzXsPLTk0N7DjRlADog78/DqQzszIx81LDu831Dh8BoQ99hWIDf40MrDrYf2@x/aeWhdiDaYGa@VCZI8tPDwcqXgw/sVwKhS6fDqyEM7D2/wjPCKBbtG7/9/QwMTrvLM1Jz8osokAA)

Comment: `ƵŽç„ÿw` can be `„ów` for another -3. `ó` is part of [05AB1E's codepage](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), unlike the other two characters `ż` and `ą`. Although it does seem to be unbound and not used by any builtin apparently... That's actually pretty interesting. TIL. :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 160 bytes

```factor
[| n s | n s t n 0 = n 1 = n present R/ .*(?<!1)[234]/ matches? 3array index ?1+
{ "Jest %d %sów.""Nie ma żadnych %sów.""Jest %d %s.""Są %d %sy."} nth sprintf ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVG7TsMwFBVrvoDxYKkSD_WRtEiIhzoiGDpQMVUdXOe2jZrawXbUhtKRr2DpAPwAKxvwEfA1OE2h8XDse3zP0dW5T69DLqzSq5-d3dvuVefyFFxrnhlwY5QwGCo95dZGcoRIYUJaUoxYCR4buI8xEk2GpIWmEc0TGLpLSQoyOPO8hQd3FmiAJWoahUozLDecDzaZRdxumQAsVNNtfQw2i-JJSdJ0GjVNUkslo6AFNkhLPn4j9061uOdlcaOV-1GsdDYo0X6QD2fK-sBRAx4rmXNL7yW1w-rJ93PvARIGBVqHDVw49Nf4F8NNHbXD_fb5nn_QC5qtfj1PSYzJtNFcJ4tIhjRH2z_yFmDXZCwqISrm421WY6wTkRPg652HMhPjf37b54ru52PxzmpsCemWYBIdSTtEfzMr62HNoA_hAlOGin1WiTtTERPXRedqVdy_)

#### How?

```
                   ! n = 122, s = "balon"
n                  ! 122
s                  ! 122 "balon"
t                  ! 122 "balon" t
n                  ! 122 "balon" t 122
0                  ! 122 "balon" t 122 0
=                  ! 122 "balon" t f
n                  ! 122 "balon" t f 122
1                  ! 122 "balon" t f 122 1
=                  ! 122 "balon" t f f
n                  ! 122 "balon" t f f 122
present            ! 122 "balon" t f f "122"
R/ .*(?<!1)[234]/  ! 122 "balon" t f f "122" R/ .*(?<!1)[234]/
matches?           ! 122 "balon" t f f t
3array             ! 122 "balon" t { f f t }
index              ! 122 "balon" 2
?1+                ! 122 "balon" 3
{ ... }            ! 122 "balon" 3 { ... }
nth                ! 122 "balon" "Są %d %sy."
sprintf            ! "Są 122 balony."
```

Comment: may need to specify a version, cause this doesn't work correctly on the latest commit

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>109</s> 106 bytes

```python
lambda n,s:[['Nie ma żadnych ','Jest %s '%n][n>0]+s+'ów'*(n!=1),f'Są {n} {s}y'][n//10%10!=1<n%10<5]+'.'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY@xboMwEIZ3nuI6RIaGOpgkSxTyAB26dKQZTABhATbCRohGGftEXbu1fS5qAyFRF9v33@/v7q86lQm@7tPgrS9oGcUUuCt3YYheWAIlhd8vGvPulAFy0XMiFSwkoAU/hvzgHZdyib4/W/Ro84eAOG6KXn8@4MwvcJaXDmnTakW8BfF0d8/1vd8elwijvs1YkQDZWcB45YJoVAWBeTfKdrCsCqZsBE8HQI6lFwI5dqeO1qqacWWntjm5ow0OBMHAcXoPKlGyWNQG8D/G1NJbY4tA3jKqjG2INtXY8iEWpZFNnKHosLWFlhX5bB7LkbOGXJR696S@sW7a4PE3EDVqZg6VhhJPD23q0zu9ke@0Ee9t9KykEHUXXQH3msEQXyeTd1EmYQT4PkS0EHz@fRU6/Ac)

Comment: Your score is actually only 103, because the question allows you to count the non-ASCII characters as 1 byte

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl056`, 79 bytes in ISO-8859-2

```perl
/ /;$_=/(?<!1)[234] /?"Są ${_}y":$`?"Jest $_"."ów"x($`>1):"Nie ma żadnych $'ów"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/NUoMwFEb3fYprytTWGRKgxUVRundGNy4dp01LFAQSJgmD6Lj0idy6U19LDNC/cXlPbs53v4LJzG8UATvEZ4QEMHwqlYaYSQYPQoKOGWxEUZOCKm2QFHnHNDNbG6qYagiQwFpekvHi4sSd3HnT2T2QBbr9fgfrdflWo7m1WqCr9oO1RBh9fVToeWytQncyRzcJg5zCzyeNeL2JwTptn5vAwqE7GilaIxQMc5oy1cVKpspMK2BUJcxcJwyhEVQx4yBLzhP@CLkwt@uYchC8P7RxoBB5Epk@dgj/I7dPJhcPXEirhOp2rTt4O@OBB5FpbnBbqxtqPPChSrJ0v9yPvWcKqciLUjN5cB1Yt@PNYF3qvbObjNR1TGgpNy/0YD5ivd6ZmSyWCVmvd4Jj1mpczzRTR1W2oBd4HqxpJvj@9w7U@FcUOhFcNXaROf55Y1/72HGdPw)

### Explanation

Match space with `/ /` which stores the number in prematch (`` $` `` ) and the noun in postmatch (`$'`). Next `$_` (which is automatically output, thanks to `-p`) is set to `"Są ${_}y"` (where `$_` is the implicit input from the implicit `-n` via `-p`) if it matches the regex `/(?<!1)[234] /` (number ends `[234]` but not `1[234]`), otherwise if `` $` ``  is not `0` it's set to `"Jest $_"."ów"x($`>1)`, where the` "ów"`suffix is added if`$'`is greater than`1`, otherwise, finally for the` 0`case it's set to`"Nie ma żadnych $'ów"`.

Thanks to [@Xcali](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72767/xcali) for saving 9 bytes!

Comment: Nice trick with the `-056` option.  Here's a little shorter way: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/NUoMwFEb3fYprytTWGRKgxUVRundGNy4dp01LFAQSJgmD6Lj0idy6U19LDNC/cXlPbs53v4LJzG8UATvEZ4QEMHwqlYaYSQYPQoKOGWxEUZOCKm2QFHnHNDNbG6qYagiQwFpekvHi4sSd3HnT2T2QBbr9fgfrdflWo7m1WqCr9oO1RBh9fVToeWytQncyRzcJg5zCzyeNeL2JwTptn5vAwqE7GilaIxQMc5oy1cVKpspMK2BUJcxcJwyhEVQx4yBLzhP@CLkwt@uYchC8P7RxoBB5Epk@dgj/I7dPJhcPXEirhOp2rTt4O@OBB5FpbnBbqxtqPPChSrJ0v9yPvWcKqciLUjN5cB1Yt@PNYF3qvbObjNR1TGgpNy/0YD5ivd6ZmSyWCVmvd4Jj1mpczzRTR1W2oBd4HqxpJvj@9w7U@FcUOhFcNXaROf55Y1/72HGdPw "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks @Xcali! Not an insignificant saving either!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>138</s> <s>123</s> 111 bytes

```python
lambda n,s:("Nie ma żadnych ",("Jest","Są")[(z:=n//10%10!=1<n%10<5)]+f' {n} ')[n>0]+s+(n!=1)*"óyw"[z::2]+'.'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZLBbptAFEWl7Myi3_AyUgTEJIGJLVUoZNNdFtl0SVmMw0yDAjOIGeRgy8t-RTaWovYHvO0uzUe0X9MHY5uqq9G793LuY-DlR92ZRyW3ryL58r014uLjb1WyapEzkIGOPXJfcKgYvP9kueweHoEEHrnj2pCAfP71jfipt4oTeXUVhWdReJpENxLPm7mfTYULa7kB10_lbZhN9dST6Pvn5G3XLUm6imOaTd1L19b-OflgEKuT1EnDAEitqiJXDdb8v8HeedstL0kWOGmE6adlwXAlGFaDCIbZ2hTVXFW9iQsDBRw6a81RWxbl0_HBOfTjSL7u0aqqW8ObkX4NB-2YpDN0F605tswAp31NFA4rts3Dio1dqMJeGwvD2bASL1XTLQ4wVOGgHZARHe5I__PSEYVeGGG0zyxYqeSRRCkMgsVkjlANyLYKQJumkF8DaLhuSwOFhOFrxM6kEOA9x4nw-pyN-f5pYoPoT2qUjCfIJ6Y5uGuMbQJY2-TGBcGKkudwAao1eGmgBIaeNy7xnQkvNR8RllAzrXlOfPtbbLf2_As)

Comment: Your score is actually only 108, because the question allows you to count the non-ASCII characters as 1 byte

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 113 bytes<sup>*</sup>

** counting each special letter as 1 byte, as allowed by the challenge*

Expects `(integer)(word)`.

```javascript
n=>w=>[`Jest`,`Są`,`Nie ma żadnych`][i=n<2?n+2:28>>n%10&n*9%98%9!=1,i%3]+` ${n?n+' '+w:w}${[[,'y','ów'][i||2]]}.`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFBU4JQFIX3/YrbGwlNQt5TZ9QJ2rdo05JhBgSsl/CeAxhD6rJf5LZd9bvoQjqlsGFx7vnuPefx4r16qZ/wVXYjZBCWC7MUppWblu3eh2nmau7j1zt@H3gIsQffH14gCv/ZdWxuilt2J/psxiaWJRRqXInrqTKdKNNLk2pcGTp9FzobgR4V1H4@y3edjW1raqFq6uc@V3HHdsscZ6e7pS9FKqNQj@RTd9EFMHpdspIxD2RCoNeDwQDOIsBhjJv0i3OcIr7MuZcRgANe1QEKtdoEGAKBjCv7EcDiwADFomkfoz3n0ZLA6f4xVGpbJDqsIsl4tc7ChPyPNISj3MaxEXLzddZINgJUG9GoUVdfJ/6btyQn1Q0s/6u33KHGqK4URjIp5uTvDg7gKDevUVb/pzQ7fwicQKW3nWIVNPciKchJJRxALRd6@QM)

#### How?

To test whether \$n\$ ends with \$2\$, \$3\$ or \$4\$ and does not end with \$12\$, \$13\$ or \$14\$, we use the expression:

```javascript
28>>n%10&n*9%98%9!=1   // 20 bytes
```

Explanation:

```javascript
28                     // the bitmask 0b0000011100
>> n % 10              // right-shifted by n mod 10
&                      //
n * 9 % 98 % 9 != 1    // this is false for 12, 13, 14, 112, 113, 114
                       // and true for other values ending with 2, 3, 4
                       // (for anything else, it doesn't matter)
```

This is somewhat convoluted but shorter than using a test with a regular expression (which would also require ES9+ for the negative lookbehind assertion):

```javascript
/(?<!1)[234]$/.test(n) // 22 bytes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BTsMwFET3OcVUAvzdGjdJu2hp0x6iy6oLqw1VqmA7jsUGuAESG5ZwD87TC3CE8L3gL@aP5s1iLubZ9MfQ@Hhv3akehkcXqK0jLCrkK37rCmWe3GQi8ZIBiXqm5QKbDRduUeSK83Qd5xZjLDldLpL8k8DE4w7UYVShkKuMwdHZ3rW1bt2Z9lbBK3QKQaV2hSlt16NC7svZ/HAz1bHuI1mJLcTvz8f165NV4AHi@v0uDvrJeOLRvEhHt4uhsWeS2pvTLpoQaSalvrjGksArhJTZ2zD8AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 73 bytes

```
≡θ0«Nie ma żadnych ηów»¿›№234§θ±¹⁼1§θ±²«Są θ ηy»«Jest θ η¿⁻1θów».
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/7@4PLMkOUNBo1BToZorObE4VUHJQMkKyOYMKMrMK9FQ8stMVchNVDi6JzElrxKoUknTGiaXgWAqHd5cDpKp5UpJTUsszSmxUshMU9BwL0pNLEkt0nDOLwUpMjI2UdJRcCzxzEtJrdAo1FHwS00HymsYampq6ii4FpYm5hRrKBliVWOkCQJIDgs@0orsmEIkx@ByZCXYiQqpOUBvIgzySi0uIdokkK98M/NKoe4sBDoJPQRquaAiekD@//@GRkYKSYk5@Xn/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≡θ0«Nie ma żadnych ηów»
```

If the first input (`θ`) is `0`, then print `Nie ma żadnych ηów`, where `η` is the second input.

```
¿›№234§θ±¹⁼1§θ±²«Są θ ηy»
```

If it ends in `2`, `3` or `4` but not `12`, `13` or `14`, then print `Są θ ηy`.

```
«Jest θ η¿⁻1θów»
```

Otherwise print `Jest θ η`, and then print `ów` if the first input is not `1`.

```
.
```

Print the final `.`.

Note that the deverbosifier thinks that `ó` doesn't need to be encoded but it actually takes three bytes to encode. (It calculates the byte count correctly for ż and ą.)

Comment: Nice! What character encoding is this submission using? It looks like this is 102 bytes in UTF-8, and you're using characters that are outside of ISO-8859-2.

Comment: @TannerSwett Charcoal has its own code page, which you can find on its GitHub wiki. It can represent characters not in its code page but this costs at least 3 bytes each time.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 74 bytes

```
`J½Ḣ Π Π.`¹ċ[Ṫ£234¹tc¹Ṫtċ∧[⁺żC`SΠ Π Πy.`|⁺ċC¹[¥`ΠΠw.`|⁰`Nie ma \ż…ṅƒ꘍ ΠΠw.
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgSsK94biiIM6gIM6gLmDCucSLW+G5qsKjMjM0wrl0Y8K54bmqdMSL4oinW+KBusW8Q2BTzqAgzqAgzqB5LmB84oG6xItDwrlbwqVgzqDOoHcuYHzigbBgTmllIG1hIFxcxbzigKbhuYXGkuqYjSDOoM6gdy4iLCIiLCIxMDRcbndpZWxvcnliIl0=)

### How?

```
`J½Ḣ Π Π.`¹ċ[Ṫ£234¹tc¹Ṫtċ∧[⁺żC`SΠ Π Πy.`|⁺ċC¹[¥`ΠΠw.`|⁰`Nie ma \ż…ṅƒ꘍ ΠΠw.
`J½Ḣ Π Π.`                   # Push string "Jest {implicit first input} {implicit second input}."
          ¹ċ                 # Is the first input not one?
            [                #  If so:
             Ṫ               #   Remove the last character (the period) from the string
              £              #   Pop and put it in the register.
               234¹tc        #    Is the last digit of the first input one of 2, 3, 4?...
                     ¹Ṫtċ∧   #    ...and is the second last digit of the first input not one?
[                            #     If so:
 ⁺żC                         #      Push "ą"
    `SΠ Π Πy.`               #      Push string "S{'ą'} {implicit first input} {implicit second input}y." (which is implicitly output)
              |              #     Otherwise:
               ⁺ċC           #      Push "ó"
                  ¹          #      Is the first input truthy? (not zero)
                   [         #       If so:
                    ¥`ΠΠw.`  #        Push string "{register}{'ó'}w." (which is implicitly output)
|                            #       Otherwise (the input is zero):
 ⁰`Nie ma \ż…ṅƒ꘍ ΠΠw.        #         Push string "Nie ma żadnych {second input}{'ó'}w." (which is implicitly output)
                             # All strings and if statements implicitly closed.
                             # If the first if statement was falsy (aka the input was one), then the string pushed at the beginning will be implicitly output.
```

Comment: `234` -> `⁺∷` for -1

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 105 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⍺=0:∊'Nie ma żadnych '⍵'ów.'⋄⍺=1:∊'Jest 1 '⍵⋄1 0≡(2 3 4∘+¨0 10)∨/⍤∊¨10 100|⍺:∊'Są'⍺⍵'y.'⋄∊'Jest'⍺⍵'ów.'}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37Uu8vWwOpRR5e6X2aqQm6iwtE9iSl5lckZCuqPereqH95crqf@qLsFpMwQrMwrtbhEwRAsCxQ3VDB41LlQw0jBWMHkUccM7UMrDBQMDTQfdazQf9S7BKj@0ApDkIhBDdAEsP7gI61AvbtAhldCjIYaChMFW1kLAA&f=XZA9DoIwGIZ3T/FtTBIosHoABxdPUKDGBkoJlhDcddO4OHoKVzf1Ij2JbUOxsD7v39fK612ebwHsvJozmvPGA3l5wHIFG0qAYfi@cF712R4G/f3s/IU0qVClio5iMWbW5CAgBAOtCylXztno2X5OgECR3joS5ehoWUxrEtDMnYv0Hmd1K0gzm4zACk4AxSqQtmI6HYNC43YYmFe0TXbEswO0NAjuFUFsziUlb/p0Uq0lK/wHQmQ@9zD/JcU1dauRtqa45NW0V3FDe/8H&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Ironic.